# stringWithFormat and Multiple line text in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios

my both code is working good..but i wants to know..who is better...
and which i use ?

first code.....

```
NSString *advance=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat :@"Pay in Advance Rs %i",pro.s_advance ];
UILabel *label1 =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,200,40)];
label1.text=advance;
[cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
[label1 release];
[advance release];
```

and second code is.....

```
UILabel *label1 =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,5,200,40)];
label1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pay in Advance Rs %i",pro.s_advance ];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
[label1 release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and second codes are equal.

The only difference is that in second one you are creating `autoreleased` object of type `NSString`. In first one you are releasing manually object of type `NSString` as it is not `autoreleased`: `[advance release];`

So there are no memory management issues and you can use any of that approaches.

I would prefer second one as code will be more cleaner.

Comment: I would recommend compiling under the iOS 5 SDK which will handle memory management for you and then you will not have to really deal with which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functional difference between those two sets of code, except for some very subtle/irrelevant memory semantics.

But I personally would use the second one, because it's shorter and easier to read.

Comment: ...thanks for suggesion...In first code...I release the string..but in second code.. i not release string....its allright?

Comment: In the first one you use `[NSString alloc]` to create the string, which will return an object that you must release later. In the second one you are using `[NSString string...]` to create the string, which will return an object that will automatically be released for you. The general rule in most cases is any object created with "alloc" or "copy" or "new" or "retain" must be released manually by you, any other object will automatically be released.